# Finding AWS ElastiCache endpoints with Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to programmatically get a list of ElastiCache endpoints from my Java app using the latest Java AWS SDK. Things don't seem to be working - I can find a valid CacheCluster, but then when I list its nodes, it's empty. Here's my code:

```
CacheCluster cc = it.next();

System.out.println("Cache node type: " + cc.getCacheNodeType());
System.out.println("Number cache nodes: " + cc.getNumCacheNodes());

List<CacheNode> listCache = cc.getCacheNodes();

System.out.println("List size: " + listCache.size());
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
Cache node type: cache.m1.small 
Number cache nodes: 1 
List size: 0
```

This seems so simple, but doesn't seem to work. I have started an ElastiCache cluster with a single node, but the list comes up empty when I call getCacheNodes(). I've tried to run this code locally and on an EC2 instance, and I get the same thing both times.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the AWS team response to [Not able to get cache nodes from ElastiCache cluster](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=282119#282119) you'll *need to use optional ShowDetails flag to obtain CacheNodes Information* via the [Class DescribeCacheClustersRequest](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/DescribeCacheClustersRequest.html) parameter of method [describeCacheClusters()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/AmazonElastiCacheClient.html#describeCacheClusters%28%29). Looking closer there is no *ShowDetails* flag though, despite being documented for this class indeed:

> An optional ShowDetails flag can be used to retrieve detailed
> information about the Cache Nodes associated with the Cache Cluster.
> Details include the DNS address and port for the Cache Node endpoint.

Presumably this actually targets [setShowCacheNodeInfo()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/DescribeCacheClustersRequest.html#setShowCacheNodeInfo%28java.lang.Boolean%29), which is *An optional flag that can be included in the DescribeCacheCluster request to retrieve Cache Nodes information*.

So the AWS team response seems imprecise and actually isn't addressing the question, why method [getCacheNodes()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/CacheCluster.html#getCacheNodes%28%29) from [Class CacheCluster](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/CacheCluster.html) isn't returning that information, both being pretty unusual for such posts.

Anyway, you might simply want to try method [getCacheNodes()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/CacheCluster.html#getCacheNodes%28%29) from [Class CacheCluster](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/CacheCluster.html) as returned by method [getCacheClusters()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/DescribeCacheClustersResult.html#getCacheClusters%28%29) from [Class DescribeCacheClustersResult](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/DescribeCacheClustersResult.html) instead, hopefully it works as advertized (i.e. I haven't tried this myself).

Good luck!

---

#### Update

Here is the code Sander used successfully to achieve his goal, confirming the approach outlined above:

```
AmazonElastiCacheClient client = new AmazonElastiCacheClient(credentials);
DescribeCacheClustersRequest dccRequest = new DescribeCacheClustersRequest();
dccRequest.setShowCacheNodeInfo(true);

DescribeCacheClustersResult clusterResult = client.describeCacheClusters(dccRequest);
```

The missing pieces should be similar to his initial solution, e.g.:

```
List<CacheCluster> cacheClusters = clusterResult.getCacheClusters();
for (CacheCluster cacheCluster : cacheClusters) {
    List<CacheNode> cacheNodes = cacheCluster.getCacheNodes();

    System.out.println("List size: " + cacheNodes.size());
}
```

Comment: You sir are correct. Here's the updated code:
`code`
AmazonElastiCacheClient client = new AmazonElastiCacheClient(credentials);
    DescribeCacheClustersRequest dccRequest = new DescribeCacheClustersRequest();    
dccRequest.setShowCacheNodeInfo(true);
DescribeCacheClustersResult clusterResult = client.describeCacheClusters(dccRequest);
`code`

Comment: @SanderSmith: Thanks for following up with your solution confirming this approach! I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: OMG, that is VERY weird, without a warn, a error or exception when trying to get .getCacheNodes(). Amazon should take care of it.

Comment: Above code returning 0 cacheCluster even though I have 1 created.  What could be the problem?

Comment: @rohitkadam19 - the default AWS region can differ depending on whether you are using the management console, the CLI or a SDK. Accordingly, it is easy to stumble about such a mismatch when for example creating something via the console manually (i.e. your ElastiCache cluster) and then trying to access it programmatically - have you checked that you are working with the same region in both cases?