# How to get Address of elasticache nodes from Java API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I am making a describeCacheClusters request as follows and get a valid response but the getCacheClusters() method returns null even though that cluster has available nodes. Is there another request I should be using or a missing parameter?

```
DescribeCacheClustersResult result = awsClient
        .describeCacheClusters(new DescribeCacheClustersRequest()
        .withCacheClusterId(ELASTICACHE_CLUSTER_ID));
```

Comment: You can generate hostname as it always has the format CLUSTER_NAME.f1xaiv.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com where 0001 is the number of the node.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding AWS ElastiCache endpoints with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691276/finding-aws-elasticache-endpoints-with-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a parameter indeed due to a somewhat confusing API design resp. documentation issue with [Amazon ElastiCache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/):

You need to add [setShowCacheNodeInfo()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/DescribeCacheClustersRequest.html#setShowCacheNodeInfo%28java.lang.Boolean%29) to your [DescribeCacheClustersRequest](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/DescribeCacheClustersRequest.html) **and** call [getCacheNodes()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/CacheCluster.html#getCacheNodes%28%29) for each [CacheCluster](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/CacheCluster.html) retrieved via [getCacheClusters()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/DescribeCacheClustersResult.html#getCacheClusters%28%29) from the [DescribeCacheClustersResult](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/model/DescribeCacheClustersResult.html) - see my answer to  the semantic duplicate [Finding AWS ElastiCache endpoints with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693016/45773) for details and code samples.