# Error when describing elasticache instance after setting endpoint in aws java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to describe my cache cluster nodes in AWS Elasticache.  I am using the example from [Finding AWS ElastiCache endpoints with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691276/finding-aws-elasticache-endpoints-with-java) (the solution code).

I use the code:

```
 DescribeCacheClustersRequest dccRequest = new DescribeCacheClustersRequest();    
    dccRequest.setShowCacheNodeInfo(true);

    elasticache.setEndpoint("ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com");
    DescribeCacheClustersResult clusterResult = elasticache.describeCacheClusters(dccRequest);
    System.out.println("cache cluster node fleet size: " + clusterResult.getCacheClusters().size());
    for (CacheCluster cacheCluster : clusterResult.getCacheClusters()) {
        List<CacheNode> cacheNodes = cacheCluster.getCacheNodes();

        System.out.println("cache cluster size: " + cacheNodes.size());
    }
```

When I run this code I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" Status Code: 400, AWS Service:
>   AmazonElastiCache, AWS Request ID: null, AWS Error Code: null, AWS
>   Error Message: null

If I remove the setEndpoint code, the code doesn't error out, but no nodes are returned and printed.  The reason I am guessing is because the US-EAST region is queried by default.

Does anyone know how I can circumvent this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting the endpoint to the EC2 endpoint not the Amazon ElastiCache endpoint.  The corrected code snippet is:

```
elasticache.setEndpoint("elasticache.us-west-1.amazonaws.com");
```

You can find a complete list of endpoints in this [document](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)